# C++ Using a template class pointer as a template parameter without giving it a parameter

Tags: c++, templates

The title is a little confusing, so hopefully I can clear that up.

I have a simple class that uses a template:

```
template <class T>
class Value
{
};
```

And another class that extends unordered_set:

```
template<class T>
class Collection : public std::unordered_set<T>
{
};
```

These classes both have some other code, but I don't think any of it is relevant to my question.

In a particular implementation of the Collection class, I want it to be able to take pointers to any Value, regardless of the template parameter that was used when creating it. In other words, I want to be able to have something semantically similar like this:

```
class ValueCollection : public Collection<Value*>
{
};

ValueCollection *vc = new ValueCollection();
vc.insert(new Value<std::string>("hello"));
vc.insert(new Value<int>(5));
```

Of course, that doesn't work. How I would obtain similar functionality?

Comment: You shall not derive from STL containers.

Comment: @ipc: unordered_set is not part of the STL, but of the C++11 standard library.

Comment: @BatchyX: It's part of C++11's STL.

Comment: The point is still quite valid- this is the bads.

Comment: My bad. My Java background got the better of me. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give you `Value` class template a common base class, making sure that it has a `virtual` destructor and using this to add your instantiated values:

```
struct ValueBase {
    virtual ~ValueBase() {}
};
template <typename T>
struct Value
    : ValueBase {
};
```

BTW, you are generally better off *not* inheriting the STL containers: They are not designed for inheritance you are most likely to cause subtle problems than benefitting from the little amount of saved work.

Comment: Wonder why I didn't think of that >_>. Thanks for the tip concerning the bad extension (this goes to everyone who mentioned it, as well). I'll refactor my code so Collection wraps it instead.